# require module fails in love2d fused executable, but succeeds when running love.exe on my project folder

Tags: lua, love2d

I followed the steps on the love2d wiki to make a fused executable for my game. When I launch the resulting fused exe, I get the below error:

```
Error: main.lua:12: module 'util/strict' not found:
    no field package.preload['util/strict']
    no 'util/strict' in LOVE game directories.
    no file 'util/strict.dll' in LOVE paths.
    no file 'flowerpowers/scripts/util/strict.lua'
    no file 'flowerpowers/data/util/strict.lua'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    main.lua:12: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [string "boot.lua"]:429: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:275>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

However, when I run my game by dragging the folder (i.e. the one that mirrors the contents of the zip I made in the fusing process: both directly contain main.lua, conf.lua and all the subfolders of my project) onto love.exe, it works like a dream.

Here's the top of my main.lua, up until the line it crashes on (note: the commented out BASEDIR was an attempt to get it to work, but it broke both the fused exe and the drag-folder method):

```
io.stdout:setvbuf("no")
love.keyboard.setKeyRepeat(true)

BASEDIR = "flowerpowers"
-- BASEDIR = ""
package.path = BASEDIR..'/scripts/?.lua;'..BASEDIR..'/data/?.lua'

package.cpath = ""
package.preload = {}

require "util/strict"
```

I've tried various combinations of individual solutions I saw suggested on similar questions, but nothing seems to work: appending package.path to the string I'm setting for package.path above, using "\\" instead of "/", using "." instead of "/", explicitly including all subfolders in the project in my package.path string, and removing subfolders from the require targets. Nothing works, unfortunately.

This is what my folder structure looks like:

```
+ FlowerPowers (the folder that I zip the contents of, not including the folder itself)
    - main.lua
    - conf.lua
    + data (contains other files and folders)
    + scripts (contains other files and folders, but only listing relevant ones)
        + util
            - strict.lua
+ bin
    - love.exe
    - [love DLLs]
+ distro
    - FlowerPowers.exe (fused executable)
    - [love DLLs]
```

Hopefully that's enough information to get started, but if I can provide any other info that would be helpful, just let me know. Totally stumped as to why it works when running my folder on love.exe, but not when they've been fused.

EDIT: My fused exe seems to work when it is run from a folder that also contains my entire project folder (i.e. FlowerPowers in the above structure). But if that folder is missing, I get this crash.

EDIT #2:  Got the  solution! Details here: https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=83142&p=206049#p206049

Working code here:

```
BASEDIR = love.filesystem.getRealDirectory("/scripts"):match("(.-)[^%.]+$")
BASEDIR = string.sub(BASEDIR, 1, string.len(BASEDIR)-1)
local myPath = BASEDIR..'/scripts/?.lua;'..BASEDIR..'/data/?.lua'
local myPath2 = 'scripts/?.lua;/data/?.lua'

package.path = myPath
love.filesystem.setRequirePath( myPath2 )
```

Comment: you require "util" but have "utils" in your folder list. is that a typo in your question or in your script?

Comment: typo in my question! fixed now. whoops...